# Empty output for Watermarked Aggregation Query in Append Mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.2.0-rc1.

I've got a Kafka `topic` which I'm querying a running watermarked aggregation, with a `1 minute` watermark, giving out to `console` with `append` output mode.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(StructField("time", TimestampType) :: Nil)
val q = spark.
  readStream.
  format("kafka").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
  option("startingOffsets", "earliest").
  option("subscribe", "topic").
  load.
  select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).as("value"))
  select("value.*").
  withWatermark("time", "1 minute").
  groupBy("time").
  count.
  writeStream.
  outputMode("append").
  format("console").
  start
```

I am pushing following data in Kafka `topic`:

```
{"time":"2017-06-07 10:01:00.000"}
{"time":"2017-06-07 10:02:00.000"}
{"time":"2017-06-07 10:03:00.000"}
{"time":"2017-06-07 10:04:00.000"}
{"time":"2017-06-07 10:05:00.000"}
```

And I am getting following output:

```
scala> -------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+                                                                    
|time|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+                                                                    
|time|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+                                                                    
|time|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+                                                                    
|time|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 4
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+                                                                    
|time|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Having a same problem, with spark 2.1. I'm reading a stream from disk, and using `.withWatermark` and groupBy(window(...)) aggregation - no data is being put out. Without watermarking data is being processed normally.

Comment: It seems to be a bug...like this one - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20065.

Comment: @RayanRal are you using "complete" mode without watermarking and "append" mode with watermarking?

Comment: @zsxwing Tried both:
`complete` mode without watermarking - output is ok,
`append` mode with watermarking - output is empty

Comment: @zsxwing 
Looks like it really waits for new files, to dump old ones to a batch. When I just put 4 files (each with 1 hour difference timestamp) and set watermark to 1 hour - it didn't write output. When I add files during the run, one by one - it creates batches, but with some kind of lag - 2 hours need to be added, to get a formed batch. 
Is there any way to create batch by-file, and not by column value?

Comment: Just in case anyone would be looking here for answer to problem in my comment - there's an option `maxFilesPerTrigger` that you can specify when reading from disk. And here's a great article series - https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html

Comment: @RayanRal Explaining your 2 hours problem here: https://gist.github.com/zsxwing/18ee545ac640d3009b793763a2e7ec8b

Comment: I understand this works for you in complete mode but not append. Can you pose the results for complete mode?

Comment: Hello All, is there any solution for this issue? what parameters we need to change ?i am also facing same issue

Comment: @BigD: can you please share your code snippet? Or, is it the same as this one?

Comment: I have posted here .. i am getting data reflected after third time when i add data to the read stream directory   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378219/spark-structured-streaming-delaying-2-batches-of-data-always?noredirect=1#comment95586679_54378219

Comment: @himanshuIIITian .. can you please let me know how did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pushing more data to Kafka should trigger Spark to output something. The current behavior is totally because of the internal implementation.

When you push some data, StreamingQuery will generate a batch to run. When this batch finishes, it will remember the max event time in this batch. Then in the next batch,
because you are using `append` mode, StreamingQuery will use the max event time and watermark to evict old values from StateStore and output it. Therefore you need to make sure generating at least two batches in order to see output.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I generated 4 Batches but still got empty output. I have updated my question with all 4 batches.

Comment: I see. Another issue is your json values are invalid. It should be `{"time":"2017-06-07 10:01:00.000"}`. If you use "complete" mode, you will see it just outputs null.

Comment: After correcting the json value, I can see the output in `complete` mode but not in `append` mode. Why ?

Comment: Also, there are no examples on `watermarking` in Spark. Can you provide me an example on it ?

Comment: to quote spark documentation - 

For a specific window ending at time T, the engine will maintain state and allow late data to update the state until (max event time seen by the engine - late threshold > T). In other words, late data within the threshold will be aggregated, but data later than the threshold will start getting dropped

Answer (score 5):

Here's my best guess:

Append mode only outputs the data after the watermark has passed (e.g. in this case 1 minute later). You didn't set a trigger (e.g. `.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")`) so by default it outputs batches as fast as possible. So for the first minute all your batches should be empty, and the first batch after a minute should contain some content.

Another possibility is that you're using `groupBy("time")` instead of `groupBy(window("time", "[window duration]"))`. I believe watermarks are meant to be used with time windows or mapGroupsWithState, so I'm not how the interaction works in this case.

Comment: I was having a similar problem while trying to group by the time variable. But changing it to window(time, ...) fixed my problem