# Why does streaming aggregation delay until two batches of data always?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.3.0.

My issue is whenever I add third batch of data in my input directory, the first batch of data getting processed and printing to console. Why?

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("micro1")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
  .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "/user/sas/sparkCheckpoint")
  .config("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata","false")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Left side of a join
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val mySchema = new StructType()
  .add("id", IntegerType)
  .add("name", StringType)
  .add("year", IntegerType)
  .add("rating", DoubleType)
  .add("duration", IntegerType)
val xmlData = spark
  .readStream
  .option("sep", ",")
  .schema(mySchema)
  .csv("tostack")

// Right side of a join
val mappingSchema = new StructType()
  .add("id", StringType)
  .add("megavol", StringType)
val staticData = spark
  .read
  .option("sep", ",")
  .schema(mappingSchema)
  .csv("input_tost_static.csv") 

xmlData.createOrReplaceTempView("xmlupdates")
staticData.createOrReplaceTempView("mappingdata")

spark
  .sql("select * from xmlupdates a join mappingdata b on  a.id=b.id")
  .withColumn(
    "event_time",
    to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID()))
  .withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")
  .groupBy(window($"event_time", "10 seconds", "10 seconds"), $"year")
  .agg(
    sum($"rating") as "rating",
    sum($"duration") as "duration",
    sum($"megavol") as "sum_megavol")
  .drop("window")
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start
```

my output showing data as below: I have started the streaming first and later added data in to the particular folder. when i add my third file the first file aggregated results are getting printed. Why?

```
     -------------------------------------------
     Batch: 0
     -------------------------------------------
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     |year|rating|duration|sum_megavol|
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     +----+------+--------+-----------+

     -------------------------------------------
     Batch: 1
     -------------------------------------------
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     |year|rating|duration|sum_megavol|
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     +----+------+--------+-----------+

     -------------------------------------------
     Batch: 2
     -------------------------------------------
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     |year|rating|duration|sum_megavol|
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
     |1963|   2.8|    5126|       46.0|
     |1921|   6.0|   15212|     3600.0|
     +----+------+--------+-----------+
```

The input data is as follows:

```
1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
2,The Mummy,1993,3.5,4388
3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
4,The Object of Beauty,1921,2.8,6150
5,Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126
6,One Magic Christmas,1963,3.8,5333
7,Muriel's Wedding,1963,3.5,6323
8,Mother's Boys,1963,3.4,5733
```

`input_tost_static.csv` dataset is as follows:

```
3,3000
4,600
5,46
```

can some one help me why spark structued streaming  showing this behaviour ? Do i need to add any settings here ?
UPDATE : I am getting results in batch 1 itself if i try to print the val before JOIN operation... the issue is coming after joining.. its delaying morethan 3 batches....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty output for Watermarked Aggregation Query in Append Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403690/empty-output-for-watermarked-aggregation-query-in-append-mode)

Comment: might be some scenarios are different ans also he has code error... i couldn't find proper solutions for this? can some one help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187399/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-bigd).

Comment: Do you get any output after Batch: 2? Do you have any gaps after Batch: 2?

Comment: @Jacek  can you please give any updates i have tried water mark 0 seconds.. but its throwing error.. any idea how to resolve this ? my data is getting delayed 3 batches.... am not getting realtime data in that case

Answer (score 0):

> I have started the streaming first

**Batch: 0** is executed right after you started the query and given no events were streamed, no output.

At this point, the event-time watermark is not set at all.

> and later added data in to the particular folder.

That could be **Batch: 1**.

The event-time watermark was then set to `current_timestamp`. In order to get any output, we have to wait `"10 seconds"` (according to `withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")`).

> when i add my third file the first file aggregated results are getting printed. Why?

That could be **Batch: 2**.

I assume the next time you added new files it was after previous `current_timestamp` + `"10 seconds"` and so you got the output.

Please note that a watermark can be just `0` which means that no late data is expected.

Comment: is there anyway that i can avoid event time based delay? my requirement is as and when data comes i need to write to hdfs ... is it possible ?

Comment: i cant add water mark as 0 as it is throwing error      The window duration (0) must be greater than 0.

Comment: UPDATE : I am getting results in batch 1 itself if i try to print the val before JOIN operation... the issue is coming after joining.. its delaying morethan 3 batches....